# SigmaJS Graph should use entire width of element instead of using a 1:1 aspect ratio

Tags: sigma.js

I'm trying to fit a network graph into a rectangular area, that's about 3.5 times wider than its height.

[image]

I'm using the ForceAtlas algorithm to deploy the nodes: is there a way to make that layout use the full width that the container allows? I've tried this with success for the circular layout: where we can multiply the X coordinates by a factor of 3.5 and get an Oval shape. However, even using that oval as a starting point for the forceatlas algorithm collapses the graph into a squared area.

e.g. hacking this into the dependency:

```
 function assignPosition(i, target) {
    target[x] = 3 * scale * Math.cos((i * tau) / l) + offset;
    target[y] = scale * Math.sin((i * tau) / l) + offset;

    return target;
  }
```

yields

[image]

but then calling using that as a basis for the forceatlas algo does not make a difference:

```
      circular.assign(graph);
      settings = forceAtlas2.inferSettings(graph);
      forceAtlas2.assign(graph, {settings: settings, iterations: 50 });
```

I think a couple of others have had similar usecases (see for example https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/753 and https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/1130) but these have stayed unanswered or do not address the core layout issue.

Can someone point me in the right direction for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forceatlas2 is a physic algo, with a system of attraction/repulsion (and a center point). it doesn't have border or aspect ratio, it just do iterations on its physic engine.

That's why it looks like an 1:1 ratio.

What you want to do is to force the FA2 to have a specific shape, and for me it's not possible.

If you want to do this, you need to create your own layout algo.

### edit

By discussing with jacomyal, we found an idea : run the forceatlas and then in the sigma reducer you can divide the x position by 4 for example, to have a 1:4 ratio.
The result will be distorted, but it works.

Comment: Nice, just gave that a go and that's actually a pretty simple/intuitive solution. It does distort some of the otherwise regular structures. In the end, we opted for flipping it to a more vertical than horizontal layout, and this actually helped to avoid some of the label-collision that we were having. Thanks!